# Different background on each menu element on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, background, drop-down-menu

I'm developping a Wordpress website for a painter, and I'd like to use paintings as backgrounds for menu elements, just like on this picture :

http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/7364/capturedcran20120509094.png

The active page has colors, the inactive ones are in black and white, and become colored on mouse over.
I'm using a premium WP theme to have a similar menu, but I don't know how to achieve this menu. (this is a dropdown menu, if there is a submenu, everything below it drops down as it appears, but there is no spacial background on the submenu).

Do you know how to achieve that, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any type of option in WP menu but you can do it by assign class for each menu from WP menu section and providing custom CSS

Like

[image]

And CSS with bg image

```
.dashboard a {
background: url(../../images/navicons/81.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ID of the items and apply a background with CSS. Then add a Greyscale script: http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/2011/08/greyscale-jquery-plugin/ You can also apply a CSS fall-back if necessary (not with grey scale, but with opacity).